# Best Way To Separate Implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have been working on code splitting for my implementations and I ended up having 3 different approaches to do it. I am not sure if code splitting is required in Java, but I intended to do it.

The first approach is to have the function inside the service class.

```
@Component("fooService")
public final class FooService {
  public Foo getFoo(UUID id) {
    Foo foo = findById(id);

    validateFoo(f);

    return foo;
  }

  private void validateFoo(Foo foo) {
    if (foo.isBanned) {
      throw new Exception("Banned...");
    }
  }
}
```

The second approach is to create a separate class and name it `FooValidity`. With this approach, I need to set `validateFoo` as static.

```
public final class FooValidity {
  public static void validateFoo(Foo foo) {
    if (foo.isBanned) {
      throw new Exception("Banned...");
    }
  }
}

@Component("fooService")
public final class FooService {
  public Foo getFoo(UUID id) {
    Foo foo = findById(id);

    FooValidity.validateFoo(f);

    return foo;
  }
}
```

The third approach is to set `FooValidity` as a `@Service()` and call it lazily.

```
@Service("fooValidity")
public final class FooValidity {
  public void validateFoo(Foo foo) {
    if (foo.isBanned) {
      throw new Exception("Banned...");
    }
  }
}

@Component("fooService")
public final class FooService {
  private final FooValidity fooValidity;

  public FooService(org.springframework.context.annotation.@Lazy FooValidity fooValidity) {
    this.fooValidity = fooValidity;
  }

  public Foo getFoo(UUID id) {
    Foo foo = findById(id);

    fooValidity.validateFoo(f);

    return foo;
  }
}
```

Which approach is the best one or do I really need to do code splitting like this?

Comment: "I am not sure if code splitting is required in Java" required is a strong word. If it doesn't cause compiler errors it's not "required"

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I also worked as a front-end developer and I did code-splitting for a Webpack project. Code splitting can create multiple bundles that can be dynamically loaded at runtime. 
I then did some research about code-splitting for Java and could not find a good result. Thus I wanted to do it by myself and made 3 different approaches. But I am really not sure if this is necessary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all correct, let me go over them:

1. If you will not use the validation in any other place
2. If Validation is a simple operation and will be used in multiple places
3. If Validation is complex are requires Spring capabilities (injecting other beans, has multiple implementations,...) and is used in multiple places

Comment: Thanks. Those are good points. I can ask those questions to myself before making such cases.